# Can I move a folder such that non-versioned files are affected remotely?

Tags: git

Suppose I have the following folder structure:

> - `My_Repository`
>
>   - `Library`
>
>     - `Bananas`
>
>       - `my_script.ook`
>       - `my_output.dat` *(unversioned)*

… and I want to change it to:

> - `My_Repository`
>
>   - `Library`
>   - `Bananas`
>
>     - `my_script.ook`
>     - `my_output.dat`

With other words, I want to move a subfolder (`Bananas`) one level up, taking all its content with it, including the unversioned `my_output.dat`.
The latter file is unversioned and should never be (imagine it being huge), however it is present in some clones of the repository.

Now, the following works just fine in my local clone:

```
git mv My_Repository/Library/Bananas My_Repository
```

However, if other clones pull this change, the result is this:

> - `My_Repository`
>
>   - `Library`
>
>     - `Bananas`
>
>       - `my_output.dat`
>   - `Bananas`
>
>     - `my_script.ook`

Is there any way to obtain the desired result here as well? I am looking for a solution that scales well with the number of moved folders and files, but I would also accept an elaborate *no* as an answer.

#### What I considered so far

- I could just move the file `my_output.dat` manually in the other clone, but this approach does not translate well to more files.
- My understanding is that Git doesn’t really care about the folder structure and tracks a file’s changes through similarity. Therefore my hopes to do this using native Git structures are rather low and I expect that I have to apply some trick (e.g., using another tool).
- I could record all my movements in a script that just needs to be executed on the other clone, but this still seems very inelegant and error-prone to me.

Comment: git can't do this. If it could, it would be an immense security flaw.

Comment: Git is a source code management tool, not a deployment system. You want a fancy deployment system. (I don't know of any that are fancy in this particular way ... but I don't really know *any*, so that's kind of unsurprising. :-) )

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this.

Git cannot track untracked files. By definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191094/discussion-between-wrzlprmft-and-flimzy).